# form submit results to load in div

Tags: html, ajax, forms, post, reload

Struggling now for a few days and editing a few codes just to send my form to the process.php and then reload the result in the div the form is.
I'm working with a bootstrap layout and don't want the page to reload / go to process.php

HTML form is working when not by ajax call so the form and process.php is ok.
Only thing is I check in process on

```
$_POST['toevoegen'] == "training toevoegen"
```

because more forms go to process.php  if I succeed the transfer to it.

HTML form just a snapshot out of it, it has more values in it.

```
    <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="process.php">
      <label>datum:</label>
      <input name="datum" id="datum" size="10" type="text" autocomplete="off" /><br><br>
       <label>club:</label>
       <select name="clubid" id="club-list"  onChange="gettrainer(this.value);">
       <option value="">Selecteer club</option>
       <?php
       foreach($results as $club) {
        ?>
       <option value="<?php echo $club["id"]; ?>"><?php echo $club["clubnaam"]; ?   ></option>
       <?php
      }
      ?> 
<input type="submit" id="submit" name="toevoegen" value="training toevoegen" />
</form>
```

The ajax call is something like this but this won't work at all for the moment.

```
<script>
      $( document ).ready(function() {  

        $('#form1').on('submit', function (e) {

          e.preventDefault();
            var form1 = document.getElementById("form1");
            var fd = new FormData(form1);

          $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'process.php',
            data: fd,
              success: function (response) {
             $("#main").html(response);
            }
          });

        });

      });
    </script>
```

Comment: _“Only thing is i check in process on
$_POST['toevoegen']”_ – and that’s the problem; because you are reacting to the form submit event here, the submit button value is not included in the dataset that you build with `new FormData(form1)`. The easiest way to fix this would be to use a hidden field inside your forms to indicate what action is to be performed in the server side, so that this does not depend on how the form was actually submitted any more.

Comment: thanks @CBroe  but now i get an error like the argument is not optional  in the jquery. so i think i still have a mistake somewhere?

Comment: What argument, where?

Comment: SCRIPT65535: Het argument is niet optioneel
jquery-3.2.1.js (8429,4)

Comment: Did you change anything about the jQuery part? And what exact line is that error message referring to?

Comment: I did not change it and it is this row
// If value is a function, invoke it and use its return value
   var value = jQuery.isFunction( valueOrFunction ) ?
the var row then ofcourse 

part of 

// Serialize an array of form elements or a set of
// key/values into a query string
jQuery.param = function( a, traditional ) {
 var prefix,
  s = [],
  add = function( key, valueOrFunction ) {

   // If value is a function, invoke it and use its return value
   var value = jQuery.isFunction( valueOrFunction ) ?
    valueOrFunction() :
    valueOrFunction;

Comment: So looks like this comes out of the depths of jQuery, when it tries to serialize the form data ... but I don’t see how an additional hidden input field could make any difference here, let alone one that would throw an error. I can only think that maybe a hidden field and a submit button of the same name might cause trouble somehow here ... can you try giving the submit button a different name/leave it out altogether, and see if that changes anything?

Comment: called the submit button 1 and the hidden field the original name but is going from bad to worse now haha.

Unable to get property 'indexOf' of undefined or null reference
somehow the JS is killing me softly

Comment: Fixed my problem with changing the code to this

<script>
      $( document ).ready(function() {  

        $('#form1').on('submit', function (e) {

          e.preventDefault();
          $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'process.php',
            data: $('#form1').serialize(),
              success: function (response) {
             $("#main").html(response);
            }
          });

        });

      });
    </script>

Answer (score 0):

changed the data field to  data: $('#form1').serialize(),

```
<script>
      $( document ).ready(function() {  

        $('#form1').on('submit', function (e) {

          e.preventDefault();
          $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'process.php',
            data: $('#form1').serialize(),
              success: function (response) {
             $("#main").html(response);
            }
          });

        });

      });
    </script>
```